# Static variable for object count in c++ classes?

Tags: c++, class, static

I would like to have a static member variable keep track of the amount of objects that have been made. Like so:

```
class test{
    static int count = 0;
    public:
        test(){
            count++;

        }
}
```

That doesn't work because, according to VC++, `a member with an in-class initializer must be constant`. So I looked around and apparently you're supposed to do:

```
test::count = 0;
```

Which would be great, but I want count to be private.

**edit:**
Oh boy, I just realized I need to do:

```
int test::count = 0;
```

I had seen something just do `test::count = 0`, so I assumed you wouldn't have to declare type again.

I'd like to know if there's a way to do this inside the class though.

**edit2:**

What I'm using:

```
class test{
    private:
        static int count;
    public:
        int getCount(){
            return count;
        }
        test(){
            count++;

        }
}
int test::count=0;
```

Now it's saying: `'test' followed by 'int' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)`

**edit3:**

Yup, forgot a semicolon after the class definition. I'm not used to having to do that.

Comment: You forgot to terminate your class definition with a `;`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Put

```
static int count;
```

In your header in the class definition, and

```
int test::count = 0;
```

In the .cpp file. It will still be private (if you leave the declaration in the header in the private section of the class).

The reason you need this is because `static int count` is a variable declaration, but you need the definition in a single source file so that the linker knows what memory location you're referring to when you use the name `test::count`.

Comment: It's saying now: `'test' followed by 'int' is illegal (did you forget a ';'?)`

Comment: @Walkerneo paste the code you wrote. Note that the header should remain the same as it was before except remove the `= 0`.

Comment: It's all in the same file by the way, I haven't separated them. Is that a problem?

Comment: @Walkerneo if it's all in the same file then you must make sure that your file is only included once in your entire project. If it's included more than once, you'll get a multiple definition error. And to clarify, the `int test::count = 0` has to be outside the class definition.

Comment: @Walkerneo and you forgot the `;` at the end of your class.

Comment: Thanks, I JUST got it. Visual c++ was telling me that count was of type "test" and then I remembered that you can make optional objects after the class definition.

Comment: yes it is. As Seth said put the initialization into a cpp file of the class. A header file only initialization is not possible at least to my knowledge.

Comment: @AloisKraus yes it is possible but you can mess it up easily by including it twice.

Answer (score 5):

Initialization of static variable within a function is allowed so a solution can be something like this

```
 class test
 {
    private:
    static int & getCount ()
    {
       static int theCount = 0;
       return theCount;
    }
    public:
    int totalCount ()
    {
       return getCount ();
    }

    test()
    {      
       getCount () ++;
    }
 };
```

in general using this technique it is possible to work around the C++ limitation regarding static member initialization in the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

`static` class members must be defined (and potentially initialized) at namespace scope, member access rules do not apply.